STUN server for NAT traversal
How do I set up a STUN server for NAT traversal in Visual Studio Code? I am working on a game project that requires client communication. Could you please guide me?
What did you try?
I attempted to join a room using the provided room ID (VR6ggB1zZgSiS) in my application. The application logs show that I successfully initiated the call process, accepted the call, set up a peer connection, and sent an offer to the target (gvDAGmrLDFh76wg).
What were you expecting?
I expected the peer connection to establish successfully, enabling communication between clients without issues.
What actually happened?
However, the connection did not work as expected. Despite the logs showing that an offer was sent, the target client did not respond or the connection failed to establish. There might be an issue with the signaling, STUN/TURN server setup, or the WebRTC configuration.

You don't set up NAT in vscode as it is an IDE, much like you don't set up NAT in vim, sublime, pencil and paper etc. What language? Please show your code.

That being said I had a small webrtc project running with coturn
